# How to demonstrate the inductance of an inductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I have some troubles to demonstrate this formula. Actually my problem is about how the length of the coil is integrated in the formula... I could understand, that the electromotive force $V_L$ is equal to $NA\frac{dB}{dt}$ ? Then I know that I must use the Ampere's theorem to replace $B$ by $i$, but the closed loop that I used has no link with the length of the inductor wire $\ell$ 
$$V_L=N\frac{d\Phi}{dt}=\frac{\mu N^2A}{\ell}\frac{di}{dt} $$

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the formula $\ell$ is the length of the coil, not the length of the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation is for a long solenoid (coil) and it assumes (ignoring end effects) that the flux density, $\vec B$, is the same in magnitude and direction inside the solenoid, and zero outside the solenoid. So if you consider a path that starts from one end (X) of the solenoid and goes through the solenoid, parallel to the axis, to the other end (Y), and then returns to X via some route outside the solenoid, the integral of $\vec B.d \vec{\ell}$ will simply be $B \ell$ in which $B$ is the magnitude of the flux density inside the solenoid, and $\ell$ is the axial length of the solenoid. So Ampère's law gives $$B \ell=\mu_0NI.$$
So you now have the link between $B$ and $I$ that you need.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the amperian closed loop that you consider ? Because if the magnetic field B is flowing inside the coil, the scalar product $B$ $dl$ is null as the coil is perpendicular to the magnetic field ... ?

Comment: (a) The closed loop is the one I described X to Y through the solenoid, parallel to its axis, and then from Y back to X by any path outside the solenoid. (b) "the coil is perpendicular to the magnetic field" You are confused about coils, solenoids in particular. You need to study the magnetic field of a solenoid in a textbook or online.

Comment: Since I wrote my answer you have added a diagram to your question. The diagram show an amperian loop surrounding a single (straight?) wire. It isn't very helpful for explaining the application of the law to a current-carrying solenoid.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean but why it is not $2l$ rather than $l$?

Comment: Because (to an approximation) $B$ is zero outside the solenoid.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: @PhilipWood : Isn't ampere equation B.l=$\mu$ Ni?

Comment: @Divya K.S Indeed it is. I've put right the silly omission. Many thanks.